# Adding functionalities in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following code in Android Studio. I would like to add two functionalities:

1. Provided that Title, Name and Street are all non-empty, clicking a final button should add the street and the name to some dictionary (address book) that I can access also from other functions as well. I will want to design a function where I can send a postcard to someone else and I will want to get their address from the address book.
2. There should be a very simple drop-down menu instead of the textField for Title, with options such as "Mr.", "Mrs.", "Dr.", etc.

   @Composable
   fun NewAdrScreen(onNavigateBack: () -> Unit) {
   var Title by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
   var Name by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
   var Street by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
   val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

   ```
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally // Center horizontally
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start // Align arrow to the left
        ) {
            IconButton(onClick = onNavigateBack) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack, contentDescription = "Back")
            }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            ) {    
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))

                TextField(
                value = Title,
                onValueChange = { newTitle -> Title = newTitle },
                label = { Text("Title") },
                singleLine = true,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
                keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                    onDone = { keyboardController?.hide() })
                )
                TextField(
                    value = Name,
                    onValueChange = { newName -> Name = newName },
                    label = { Text("Name") },
                    singleLine = true,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
                    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                        onDone = { keyboardController?.hide() })
                )

                TextField(
                    value = Street,
                    onValueChange = { newStreet -> Street = newStreet },
                    label = { Text("Street") },
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
                    singleLine = true,
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
                    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                        onDone = { keyboardController?.hide() })
                )


            }
        }
    }
   ```

   }